# Riccati differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The Riccati differential equation, $y'=x+y^2$ is special equation.
I know that how can I solve it, but my problem is that I don't have initial conditions, and I firstly need a particular solution. How to find the particular solution, please?

Comment: the solution comntains the Bessel-function

Comment: the Riccati form for 2nd order is

Comment: No trivial particular solution, you should find one from the general solution.

Comment: What is the particular solution yp for this equation? can I guess yp=1?

Answer (score 1):

$$y'=x+y^2$$
The change of function $y=-\frac{u'}{u}$ tramsforms the ODE to :
$$u''+xu=0$$
This second order linear ODE is of the Bessel kind.
$$u= c_1\sqrt{x} J_{1/3} (\frac{2}{3}x^{3/2}) +c_2\sqrt{x} J_{-1/3} (\frac{2}{3}x^{3/2}) $$
In order to compute $y=-\frac{u'}{u}$ , see the formula of the derivatives of the Bessel functions : http://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselJ/20/01/02/